# LANGUAGE=lv:es_ES

Tags: locale

No idea how to open any folders or files to be edited - permission denies... Nothing in the terminal seems to work concerning locales.

Most of the programs I install are in Spanish! Man, I don't hablo Spanish.

`/etc/default/locale` contains:

```
LANG=lv_LV.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC="lv_LV.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="lv_LV.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="lv_LV.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="lv_LV.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="lv_LV.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="lv_LV.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="lv_LV.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="lv_LV.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="lv_LV.UTF-8"
LANGUAGE="lv:es_ES"
```

What is that last line?

I am positive that this is a duplicate, but I just cannot find it. Please, let me be aware of how to fix my problem at root, be it personal help or direction to another article! Thanks!

**In terminal 'locale' outputs this:**

```
LANG=lv_LV.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=lv:es_ES
LC_CTYPE="lv_LV.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=lv_LV.UTF-8
LC_TIME=lv_LV.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="lv_LV.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=lv_LV.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="lv_LV.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=lv_LV.UTF-8
LC_NAME=lv_LV.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=lv_LV.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=lv_LV.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=lv_LV.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=lv_LV.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: Can you please run the `locale` command and let us know what it outputs by editing your question.

Comment: I posted an answer about getting rid of Spanish. There seems not to be any general problem with the locale. As regards the permissions problem, you need to provide more info to get help.

Comment: As if I knew what to provide for help. -.-'

Answer (score 2):

Finally!

I don't know what I did, but I will tell what I used until I found that it's fine again. **Sorry, I don't know the order of these actions I took!**

I did sudo apt-get upgrade for the first time in months, so maybe this contibuted, too.

Looked at my locales to know which ones i have

```
sudo locale -a
```

Deleted my locale (**maybe don't delete yours, choose this action last**)

```
sudo localedef --delete-from-archive lv_LV
```

Then this thing:

```
sudo locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

In console I wrote

```
gedit ~/.profile
```

And put in the following at the end of the file **(btw, i think this is the one that did it)**

```
LANG="lv_LV.UTF-8" 
LANGUAGE="lv_LV:en"
```

After I relogged, it showed me an **error, because of deleting my locale**, so I went to Language Support and reinstalled my language.

```
$ locale
LANG=lv_LV.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=lv_LV:en
LC_CTYPE="lv_LV.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=lv_LV.UTF-8
LC_TIME=lv_LV.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="lv_LV.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=lv_LV.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES=lv_LV.UTF-8
LC_PAPER=lv_LV.UTF-8
LC_NAME=lv_LV.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=lv_LV.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=lv_LV.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=lv_LV.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=lv_LV.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

Also, I had to apply language settings to the whole system and reboot.

Comment: I wonder if i can get everything in Latvian. I made it LANGUAGE=lv_LV:lv, but all the terminal commands are in English, except for the messages that tell me that something is not installed - there's Latvian, but it cannot read some characters and they are shown like this �

Comment: The strings which are displayed in English are probably not (yet) translated to Latvian. Please don't bring up multiple issues under one question. Ask another question, if needed.

Answer (score 0):

As regards Spanish, I suggest this:

- Open *System Settings -> Language Support*
- Drag the Spanish item below the English item
- Click the *Apply System-Wide* button.

Comment: Thanks, but there is no such a thing as Spanish in there anymore. Only Latvian > English. I would have figured it out if it was that simple. What is going on in my situation?